# Uploading an image in s3 using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to s3 using node js. I'm using multer-s3.
When I try to open the image from s3 it shows"Preview not available.Your file may be corrupted".I tried fs too but still the same result.

```
services/file-upload.js

     const s3Config = new aws.S3({
        secretAccessKey: config.awsCredentials.secretAccessKey,
        accessKeyId: config.awsCredentials.accessKeyId,
        region: config.awsCredentials.region,
        bucket: 'bucketname',
    });

    const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
      if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
          cb(null, true)
      } else {
          cb(null, false)
      }
    }

    const multerS3Config = multerS3({
      s3: s3Config,
      bucket: 'bucketname',
      metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
      },
      key: function (req, file, cb) {
          console.log(file)
          cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname)
      }
    });

    const upload = multer({
      storage: multerS3Config,
      fileFilter: fileFilter,
      limits: {
          fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 // we are allowing only 5 MB files
      }
    })
controller.js
const upload = require('../services/file-upload');
var Uploader = require('s3-image-uploader');
const singleUpload = upload.single('file');
singleUpload(req, res, function(err) {
                 if (err) {
                   return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'Image Upload Error', detail: err.message}] });
                 }

                return res.json({'imageUrl': "uploaded successfully"});
              });
```

Comment: Is the file is greater than 5MB?

Comment: no it is less than 5MB

Comment: Previously I was having the same problem with file uploading on Node.js using Multer and fs but it is for the Angular.js and Node.js RestAPI. I think it may also help you out with S3. You need to add transformRequest: []  follow this link for explaination https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284412/files-are-corrupted-when-upload-image-files-and-xlsx-in-ng-file-upload-in-angul

Comment: if possible can you share the code.it would be  a great help

Comment: when I used this library it worked fine with me without any error.

clone https://github.com/rahil471/file-upload-with-angularjs-and-nodejs.git

Comment: will it upload in s3?

Comment: what you are using for frontend in S3?

Comment: I'm using it in backend. I want to upload an image on s3 using node js.

Comment: I have not worked on S3, so I don't know how you are using it there. You mean there is no frontend like <input type=files ...

Comment: I'm just working in backend

Comment: but there is an error on frontend while sending upload data to the backend that is why you are getting corrupted data. In my case, it was like this.

Comment: I'm sending the request in postman

Comment: I have not done it with POSTMAN. I have done it using Angular.js i.e AJAX. So, I don't know much about your problem. The problem may be POSTMAN the way it is sending data there must be missing something because I solve the problem in my Angular AJAX